# How to share Y-axis scale between several charts [Recharts]?

Tags: charts, scale, recharts, yaxis

I have several bar charts on the same page. I want all of them to share y-axis domain (to have the same scale and ticks). But I still want the y-axis domain value for the main(first one) chart to be calculated automatically

So I probably have to obtain access to the automatically calculated y-axis domain value of the main chart.

How? Or can you suggest another approach?

Comment: Could you provide a graphic example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @pablogarcor Thanks for your comment, I've found a solution already. Unfortunately, I don't have enough time for sandbox example right now. But I can share more info on the topic if somebody needs it

Comment: more info about the resolution would be great :) Thank you

Comment: @pablogarcor https://github.com/recharts/recharts/pull/2770. getNiceTickValues is what I was looking for